# Presenting spline terms from a Cox model

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, splines, hazard

In the Survival vignette entitled "Spline terms in a Cox model"

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/splines.pdf

on page 3 there is this graph:

[image]

The plot is showing the effect of Age which was fitted as a spline term in a Cox model. In this plot, the centering was set at age = 50, so the y axis is relative to that (hence the y axis = 1 at x = 50).

My question: Can we also call the Y axis here Hazard Ratio? This seems sensible to me as the plot is showing the exponentiated difference (i.e. ratio) between y at x=50 and y at all other x values.

Comment: Yes, because if you look, you will see that the term (which represents the coefficient by age) in the plot function is encased in `exp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because if you look at the code, you will see that the term (which represents the coefficient by age) in the plot function is encased in `exp()`. And in this case the reference value for the Hazard Ratio (HR) is set to be the age 50 (this is explained in the text of the vignette).
When you use splines representing HRs you always need to set a reference value to compare the rest of covariate values to. In this case the HR line represents the value of the ratio for each age over age 50.

I'll give more detailed if you are missing something.

Comment: Thank you @jmarkov. Yes, I saw the code in the vignette and indeed it seemed that the y axis is basically the hazard ratio. It just seemed strange to call the y axis "Relative death rate" rather than "Hazard ratio", which, at least in my mind, is more readily used. Of course, I'm not complaining about the minor detail of labelling the y axis...rather I just wanted to ensure I understood correctly!

Comment: Yes you are right. It’s a bit confusing because when you only include the linear effect the HR ratio is constant at all the values of the covariates, that is $\frac{Hazard(x+1)}{Hazard(x)}= HR$ for all $x$, and we tend to forget about this important detail sometimes. But if it’s a spline the effect changes across $x$ so you need to specify a reference value to interpret it. Please, accept the question if you are happy with the answer. Thank you